# Передача значений через конструктор в производный и базовый класс

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

Проблема такова, есть несколько классов, один базовый, и пару производных.
Сам класс с прототипами в файле **xxxx.hpp**, вся реализация в файле **xxxx.cpp**.
В производном классе есть конструктор который передает значение в базовый класс, если в самом **xxxx.hpp** файле прописать:

```
derived(int x, int y) : base1(x), base2(y) {
    std::cout << "Создание derived объекта\n";
}
```

то все ОК.

Но если попытаться написать это все в **xxxx.cpp**:

```
derived::derived(int x, int y) : base1(x), base2(y) {
    std::cout << "Создание derived объекта\n";
}
```

то кидает:

```
Redefinition of 'derived'
```

Сам файл *.hpp*:

```
class base1
    {
    protected:
        int i;

    public:
        base1(int i);
        ~base1();
    };

    class base2
    {
    protected:
        int k;

    public:
        base2(int k);
        ~base2();
    };

    class derived : public base1, public base2
    {
    public:
        derived(int x, int y) : base1(x), base2(y) {};
        ~derived();
        void show();
    };
```

Файл *.cpp*:

```
base1::base1(int i) {
    this->i = i;
    std::cout << "Создание base1\n";
}

base1::~base1() {
    std::cout << "Разрушение base1\n";
}

base2(int k) {
    this->k = k;
}

base2::~base2() {
    std::cout << "Разрушение base2\n";
}

derived::derived(int x, int y) : base1(x), base2(y) {
    std::cout << "Создание derived объекта\n";
}

derived::~derived() {
    std::cout << "Разрушение derived объекта\n";
}

void derived::show() {
    std::cout << i << " " << k << std::endl;
}
```

Как правильно передать значения в файле .cpp?

Comment: `derived(int x, int y) : base1(x), base2(y) {};` - это тоже определение. Вы определяете конструктор и там, и там, о чем вам и говорит компилятор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы же уже *определили* конструктор в hpp:

```
derived(int x, int y) : base1(x), base2(y) {};
```

Просто *объявите* его там:

```
derived(int x, int y);
```

Comment: Все, сработало, я учусь по книге, в книге этого просто нет.

Comment: Вряд ли. Это азы; скорее всего, вы просто на что-то не обратили внимания.